# How do I print output in new line in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do I print a new line in PL/SQL? I'm after something similar to '\n' in the C language.

Example:

```
begin

    dbms_output.put_line('Hi, good morning friends');

end;
```

I need the output is like this:

```
hi,
good 
morning
friends
```

Answer (score 42):

In PL/SQL code, you can use: DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 41):

You can concatenate the CR and LF:

```
chr(13)||chr(10)
```

(on windows)

or just:

```
chr(10)
```

(otherwise)

```
dbms_output.put_line('Hi,'||chr(13)||chr(10) ||'good' || chr(13)||chr(10)|| 'morning' ||chr(13)||chr(10) || 'friends');
```

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you need to use this trick:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Hi' || chr(10) || 
                     'good' || chr(10) || 
                     'morning' || chr(10) || 
                     'friends' || chr(10));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
dbms_output.put_line('Hi,');
dbms_output.put_line('good');
dbms_output.put_line('morning');
dbms_output.put_line('friends');
```

or

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi, ' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 
                     'good' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
                     'morning' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
                     'friends' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||);
```

try it.

Answer (score 5):

Pass the string and replace space with line break, it gives you desired result.

```
select replace('shailendra kumar',' ',chr(10)) from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Hi, '||CHR(10)|| 'good'||CHR(10)|| 'morning' ||CHR(10)|| 'friends');

    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   TYPE MESSAGE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100);
   MESSAGE_   MESSAGE;
   PROCEDURE write_
   IS
      counter   INT := 0;
   BEGIN
      MESSAGE_ :=
         MESSAGE ('Hi,',
                  'good',
                  'morning',
                  'friends');
      FOR i IN 1 .. MESSAGE_.COUNT
      LOOP
         counter := counter + 1;
         MESSAGE_ (counter) := MESSAGE_ (i);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (MESSAGE_ (counter));
      END LOOP;
   END;
BEGIN
   write_;
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the C approach, you can use the replace function to replace c-style escape sequences in your string literal.

This should not be seen as a widely recommended solution.

```sql
declare
  c_lf constant char(1) := chr(10);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(replace('hi,\ngood\nmorning\nfriends','\n',c_lf));
end;
/
```